# Given that $ \gcd(a, k) \neq 1 $, determine the smallest positive integer $ n > 1 $ for which $ a^n \equiv a \mod k $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Given that $ \gcd(a, k) \neq 1 $,  determine the smallest positive integer  $ n > 1 $  for which $ a^n \equiv a \mod k $.

I am intrigued about the existence of such an $ n $ and the methodology to find it.

For example,

$$4 \equiv 4 \mod 18$$
$$4^2 \equiv 16 \mod 18$$
$$4^3 \equiv 10 \mod 18$$
$$4^4 \equiv 4 \mod 18$$
Therefore $n = 4$ for $a = 4, k = 18$.

$$4 \equiv 4 \mod 12$$
$$4^2 \equiv 4 \mod 12$$
Therefore $n = 2$ for $a = 4, k = 12$

$$4 \equiv 4 \mod 24$$
$$4^2 \equiv 16 \mod 24$$
$$4^3 \equiv 16 \mod 24$$
Therefore it doesn't exist for $a = 4, k = 24$.

My questions:

1. Is there any terminology of this $n$? What are the prerequisites for $ a $ and $ k $ concerning the existence of $ n $?
2. Given $ a $ and $ k $, how can we determine this $ n $ instead of brute force? (For example, reduce this problem to multiplicative order for another pair of coprime $a', k'$.) Is there any association between this $n$ and Euler's totient function/the Carmichael function?

Comment: I don't know that there's a closed-form formula, but I think the standard way to approach this would be to write $a=bc$ where $(b,c)=1$ and all the primes dividing $c$ also divide $k$. The answer then depends on the multiplicities of the prime factors shared by $c$ and $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such an $n$ exists. Let $d=\gcd(a,k)$, and write $a=da'$, $k=dk'$. Since $a^n\equiv a\pmod{k}$, then $a(a^{n-1}-1)\equiv 0\pmod{k}$, so $a'(a^{n-1}-1)\equiv 0\pmod{k'}$. Because $\gcd(a',k')=1$, this forces $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{k'}$, which in turn requires $\gcd(a,k')=1$.

Conversely, assume that $\gcd(a,k')=1$. Then the image of $a$ in the units modulo $k'$ has order $r$ for some $r$, so $a^r\equiv 1\pmod{k'}$. Then $a'a^r\equiv a'\pmod{k'}$, so multiplying through by $d$ we get $a^{r+1}\equiv a\pmod{k}$.

Thus: $n$ exists if and only if $\gcd(a,\frac{k}{\gcd(a,k)}) = 1$. This occurs precisely if and only if for every prime $p$ that divides both $a$ and $k$, if $p^i\mid k$ then $p^i\mid a$.

Determining the smallest $n$ is equivalent to determining the order of $a$ modulo $k'$, so any algorithm for determining the order of $b$ modulo $n$ when $\gcd(n,b)=1$ will do.